# Do I need to copy dynamic memory in my structs when resizing a dynamic array of structs?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a dynamic array, where each element is a struct that contains a dynamically allocated character array among other things.


When I resize the array, I create a new array that's about 50% bigger than the old array, copy the data from the old array into the new one, and delete the old one.

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct Thing
{
    char* str; /* dynamic memory */
    int num;
    int other_data;
} thing;

typedef struct ThingStream
{
    thing* things; /* dynamic memory */
    int capacity;
    int size;
} thing_stream;

void resize_thing_stream(thing_stream* ts)
{
    int new_capacity;
    thing* new_things;
    int i;

    new_capacity = ts->capacity + ts->capacity / 2;
    new_things = malloc(new_capacity * sizeof(thing));

    for(i = 0; i < ts->size; i++)
    {
        new_things[i] = ts->things[i];
        /* here is where I would copy the str data */
    }

    free(ts->things);
    ts->things = new_things;
    ts->capacity = new_capacity;
}
```

Can I just expect the `str` to be in the new array, or do I need to copy the `str` data into the new array?

Comment: use simply `realloc`.

Comment: You don't need to copy the memory of the string. Each element holds a pointer to an allocated memory so there is no need to reallocate that. So the answer is yes, you can expect the `str` to be in the new array.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen other questions and answers that seemed to suggest freeing dynamic memory containing dynamic memory could lead to a memory leak.

Comment: In order to free the memory you have to free the string in each element first, then free the element itself. In such case you will not have any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by something simpler. Lets say you write text to a buffer, then you want to increase `buf` size and add more characters to it. The easiest way is to use `realloc`:

```
int main()
{
    char *buf;
    buf = malloc(4);
    strcpy(buf, "123");

    buf = realloc(buf, 7);
    strcat(buf, "456"); //buf still contains 123
    puts(buf);//output: 123456

    free(buf);
}
```

You can achieve the same thing with `malloc`. But to use `malloc` a second time, you have to save the old string in to a different string, free the old allocation, allocate a larger buffer, and copy the old string. Example:

```
char *buf;
buf = malloc(4);
strcpy(buf, "123");

char *temp = strdup(buf);   //save the old string
free(buf);                  //free the old string
buf = malloc(7);            //allocate new size
strcpy(buf, temp);          //copy the old string
strcat(buf, "456");         //finally the string is ready
free(temp);                 //cleanup temp variable

puts(buf);

free(buf);
```

To put this in some structure:

```
typedef struct string_t
{
    char* data;
    int capacity;
} string;

void string_reserve(string *str, int capacity)
{
    str->data = realloc(str->data, capacity);//str->data was initialized to zero
    str->capacity = capacity;
}

int main()
{
    string str;

    //initialize str:
    str.data = 0;
    str.capacity = 0;

    string_reserve(&str, 4);
    strcpy(str.data, "123");

    string_reserve(&str, 7);
    strcat(str.data, "456");
    puts(str.data);

    //free memory
    free(str.data);

    return 0;
}
```

Again you can achieve the same thing with `malloc`, but you have to be more careful.